# Hyperplanes and Linear Dependence

Tags: linear-algebra

In one of books that I'm studying, I've come across the following proposition:

"Let $x_0, x_1, ...,x_n$ be $n+1$ points in $R^n$ that are contained in no hyperplane. Define

\begin{align*} y_i=x_i - x_0 \end{align*} for $i=1,2,...,n$. Then $y_1, ...,y_n$ are linearly independent."

Just in case, a hyperplane $H(p,\alpha)$ where $p \in R^n$ and $\alpha$ is scalar is defined in my book as follows:
$$H(p,\alpha) :=\bigl\{x\in R^n\,\bigm| \, p\cdot x=\alpha \bigr\} $$

My book attempted to prove it using the contrapositive argument: if $y_1, ..., y_n$ are assumed linearly dependent, then there are $n$ scalars $p_1, ..., p_n$ such that 
$$p_1 y_1 +p_2y_2 + ... +p_ny_n = \bar0$$
I'm stuck after this point of the proof. The book says that the vector $p=(p_1,p_2,...,p_n)$ formed by using the scalars $p_1, .. ,p_n$ satisfies that $p\cdot y_i = 0$ for $i=1,2,...n$, which in turn implies that $p\cdot x_i =p \cdot x_0$ thus $x_0, x_1,...,x_n$ are contained by the same hyperplane $H(p,p \cdot x_0)$. But I couldn't see that the vector $p$ satisfies $p\cdot y_i = 0$ for all $i=1,2,...n$, linear dependence can't imply it. Is the book's proof correct or is there something missing?

Thanks!

Comment: That statement doesn't follow, as you said.  Are you sure you haven't left something out?  Consider the $y_i$ as the columns of a matrix $Y$ and consider $p$ as column vector. Then we have $Ap=\mathbf0,$ which means that the dot products of $p$ with the transposes of the *rows* of $Y$ are all $0$, but that's not the claim made in your question.  I don't see how to rescue this argument, but maybe I'm missing something simple.  If you don't get a resolution here, you should certainly take this question to your instructor.